# Q format of forward FFT of fixed version of KISS FFT

Tags: fft

I have some question about fixed version kiss_fft's butterfly computation.

in "kf_bfly2", input divide by 2 use "C_FIXDIV",

in "kf_bfly3", input divide by 3 use "C_FIXDIV",

in "kf_bfly4", input divide by 4 use "C_FIXDIV",

in "kf_bfly5", input divide by 5 use "C_FIXDIV",

in "kiss_fftr" also use "C_FIXDIV",from the point of view of FFT algorithm,it's no use, It seems using "C_FIXDIV" just to prevent overflow.

but if the input is Q15, what's the output Q value?

the output Q value is consistent with input's?

whether the output magnitude is smaller than the expected?

I'm really puzzled.

Comment: i guess i would have to see the manual or the description or the code for this kiss FFT.  are you looking for a fixed-point FFT code written in C?

Comment: yes, i  studied the source code of kiss fft, it's architecture is really good,include float and fixed version, very suitable for embedded system,

Comment: can you point me to the source code?

Comment: here:    https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/files/kissfft/

Comment: the Q point is preserved.

Comment: I see, if the data type of input data sequence is int16, then you can treat the data as Q15. all of C_FIXDIV's effet is to divide the FFT output by 'N', just prepare for the IFFT because IFFT has a factor that's "1/N"